# Getting all the active jobs from Quartz.NET scheduler

Tags: quartz.net

How I can get all the active jobs scheduled in the Quartz.NET scheduler? I tried the GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs() but it is returning always 0.

Comment: The method is not cluster aware, therefore, setting `quartz.jobStore.clustered`to false will return the correct number

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem, I want the current running job in a clustered environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That method doesn't seem to work.
The only solution I had found was to loop through all the jobs:

```
var groups = sched.JobGroupNames;
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] names = sched.GetJobNames(groups[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < names.Length; j++)
        {
             var currentJob = sched.GetJobDetail(names[j], groups[i]);
        }
    }
```

When a job is found it means that it is still active.
If you set your job as [durable](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html), though, it will never be deleted if there are no associated trigger.
In that situation this code works better:

```
var groups = sched.JobGroupNames;
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] names = sched.GetJobNames(groups[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < names.Length; j++)
        {
            var currentJob = sched.GetJobDetail(names[j], groups[i]);
            if (sched.GetTriggersOfJob(names[j], groups[i]).Count() > 0)
            {
                // still scheduled.
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

I did some debugging to see what happens with `GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs()`.
As a matter of fact it returns the job being executed but the elements are remove from the collection as soon as the job is executed.
You can check the 2 functions `JobToBeExecuted` and `JobWasExecuted` in the QuartzScheduler class.

Comment: I want to get the running jobs? The above method will return all the jobs that are paused and running.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem, I want the current running job in a clustered environment.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler loop option would be to get all of the job keys and iterate over them.  This implementation is for a minimal API example.  It gets all `JobKeys` from the scheduler and then iterates over each on to get the details and execution schedule.  More details available in this sample repo: [QuartzScheduler](https://github.com/bnolan001/QuartzScheduler).  If a job doesn't have a schedule, or it's scheduled execution has completed and there are no future executions planned then the job will not be included in the list of returned jobs.

```cs
            app.MapGet("/schedules", async (ISchedulerFactory sf) =>
            {
                var scheduler = await sf.GetScheduler();
                var definedJobDetails = new List<JobDetailsDto>();

                var jobKeys = await scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());
                foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
                {
                    var jobDetail = await scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
                    var jobSchedule = await scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
                    if (jobDetail != null && jobSchedule != null)
                    {
                        definedJobDetails.Add(new JobDetailsDto(
                            jobDetail.Key.Name,
                            jobDetail.Key.Group,
                            jobDetail.Description,
                            jobSchedule.First().GetPreviousFireTimeUtc(),
                            jobSchedule.First().GetNextFireTimeUtc())
                        );
                    }
                }

                return definedJobDetails;
            })
```